# Params for a Post to a Page with new Timeline layout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-page

Anyone with info concerning posting to a Page with the new Timeline layout via the Graph API?

How will it differ from the current posts, meaning can you specify if your post will be displayed on the left, on the right, starred (full width) or pinned to the top?

Seems even PDCs don't have that info...